# Traversing through a linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node
{
    int item;
    struct node *link
};

main()
{
    struct node *start,*list;
    int i;
    start = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list = start;
    start->link = NULL;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        list->item = i;
    list->link = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    }
    list->link = NULL;
    while(start != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",start->item);
    start = start->link;
    }
}
```

As the title suggests in this i am trying to traverse through a linked list itteratively
the expected output is
0
1
.
.
9
and the observed output is : 9
What is wrong with the code ?

Comment: in your for loop where you allocate the memory you forgot to add one more statement `list = list->link`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just because of one statement in your code.
You forgot to point to the next link, when you tried to allocate the new link.
Because of that you were allocating only at one pointer, thus having memory leak.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node
{
    int item;
    struct node *link
};

main()
{
    struct node *start,*list;
    int i;
    start = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list = start;
    start->link = NULL;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {   
        list->item = i;
        list->link = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        list = list->link;
    }   
    list->link = NULL;
    while(start != NULL)
    {   
        printf("%d\n",start->item);
        start = start->link;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You aren't pointing `list` at the next node after you create it, so you're just overwriting the previous node each time. Try this:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    list->item = i;
    list->link = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list = list->link;
}
```