# Linked List filling empty list

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct Node
{
 int val;
 struct Node *next;
};
struct List
{
 struct Node *head;
 struct Node *tail;
 int size;
};
typedef struct List *List;
```

This is my node and list, I want to add each i value to the node one by one by creating a new node in every iteration, but my program crashes I don't know what is the reason

```
    int i;
    List origin;
    List myList = (struct List*)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    myList->head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    myList->head->next = NULL;
    myList->tail = myList->head;
    origin=myList;
    

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        myList->head->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

        myList->head->next->val = i;

        myList->head->next = myList->head->next->next;

        myList->head->next->next = NULL;           

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traversing through a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757732/traversing-through-a-linked-list)

Comment: no it does not @DavidCullen

Comment: What is `struct ListRecord` type?

Comment: @swag2198 mistyped it should be List only

Comment: Look closely at `myList->head->next->next`. What does `myList->head->next->next` contain at this point? It's an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues:

- You are not traversing the list at all.
- You are mutilating the list `head` pointer and not updating the `tail` pointer.
- You are using `head` as a dummy node. It is good practice to set its value to some special marker, say -1.
- Better use a temporary `temp` node to traverse and `newnode` for inserting new nodes to avoid uninitialized pointer access and assignments.

**Modified `main()` function:**

```c
int main()
{
    int i;
    // List origin;
    List myList = (struct List*)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    myList->head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    myList->head->val = -1; /* Set a value to the dummy first node */
    myList->head->next = NULL;
    myList->tail = myList->head;
    // origin = myList;
    
    struct Node* temp = myList->head; /* Use a temporary pointer to traverse */
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        struct Node* newnode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newnode->val = i;
        newnode->next = NULL;
        
        temp->next = newnode;
        temp = newnode;         /* Update temporary head to the new node */
        myList->tail = newnode; /* Update the tail to last node */
    }

    temp = myList->head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", temp->val);
        if(temp != myList->tail)
            printf("->");
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
-1->0->1->2->3->4
```

Also take care in deallocating the `malloc`ed memory using `free()` once you are done with the list. Also I did not understand the purpose of `List origin`, so I commented out that part.

Answer (score 0):

To find the problem, we can add some debug output:

```c
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        myList->head->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        printf("myList->head->next = %p\n", myList->head->next);
        myList->head->next->val = i;
        printf("myList->head->next->next = %p\n", myList->head->next->next);
        myList->head->next = myList->head->next->next;
        printf("myList->head->next = %p\n", myList->head->next);
        if (NULL == myList->head->next) {
            printf("We just set our next pointer to NULL, so we should stop now.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        myList->head->next->next = NULL;
    }
```

We get this output:

```
myList->head->next = 0x7f8062c05800
myList->head->next->next = 0x0
myList->head->next = 0x0
We just set our next pointer to NULL, so we should stop now.
```

I made these changes to the initialization loop:

```c
    struct Node *current = myList->head;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        current->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        current->next->val = i;
        current->next->next = NULL;
        current = current->next;
    }
```

I also added an output loop to verify that the initialization worked:

```c
    current = myList->head->next;
    while (current) {
        printf("%p = %d\n", current, current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
```

**Output**

```
0x7fced6405800 = 0
0x7fced6405810 = 1
0x7fced6405820 = 2
0x7fced6405830 = 3
0x7fced6405840 = 4
```

**Note**

You weren't doing anything with the tail pointer, so I will let you figure out how you want to handle that.